# telnet: Name or service not known

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, remote-access, telnet

When I accessed a remote host using telnet I got an error like this:

```
root@nani-Inspiron-3520:/home/nani# telnet amsys@192.168.0.4
telnet: could not resolve amsys@192.168.0.4/telnet: Name or service not known
root@nani-Inspiron-3520:/home/nani#
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want your username in the original command: just type `telnet 192.168.0.4 23` (with the 23 being for the port) and then it will ask for your username and password. With what you're doing, it will assume the whole thing to be an address.